# Validar Formato Dirección MAC en javascript

Tags: javascript

quisiera saber como validar que el formato de la dirección MAC que se ingrese en un input sea válido.
Por ejemplo que cuando el usuario escriba: A5:B6:FA:C1:A2:35 algún código de javascript lo valide.
Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [ask] y de paso checa el [tour]; una vez hecho lo anterior, edita e indica que llevas hecho y donde tienes dudas

Comment: Que has intentado hasta el momento, ya realizaste alguna investigación previa a la pregunta. De paso te dejo los siguientes enlaces, para que mejores tu pregunta.
[¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878)

Comment: saludos te recomiendo investigar acerca del tema existen ya soluciones para esto , intentalo y cuando tengas problemas con ello postea tu error, en tanto revisa esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010552/jquery-javascript-mac-address-validation

Comment: Gracias @DiegoAvila y una disculpa a todos, es que realmente no tenía nada hecho. saludos!

Comment: Mas fresco que una lechuga! xD

Comment: Exactamente @OrlandoDeLaRosa :'v jaja Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente expresión regular

```
/^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$/
```

```js
function validarMac( valor ) {
  let regex = /^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$/;
  let tag   = document.getElementById('tag');
  if( regex.test( valor ) ) {
    tag.style.color = 'green';
    tag.value = 'Es una MAC Address!';
  } else {
    tag.style.color = 'red';
    tag.value = 'No es una MAC esto :(';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="validarMac( this.value )">
<input type="text" id="tag" disabled>
```

Comment: Gracias Alberto Siurob, es lo que buscaba.